# Uncaught Error: RangeError (index): Index out of range: index should be less than 6: 6

Tags: dart

hi folks in newbie in programming what is missing in my code

```
  void main(){
  print(fib(5));
   }
    int fib(int n){
     List<int> table = List<int>.filled(n+1,0,growable:true);
    table[1] = 1;
    for(var i = 0; i<=n; i++){ 
    table[i+1] +=table[i];
     table[i+2] +=table[i];
    }
   return table[n];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You `table` is a list with `n+1` spots.

Then you have a variable `i` that runs from `0` to `n`.

And you access the list for the spots `i`, `i+1`, `i+2`.

But if `i` reaches `n` at some point in the loop, that becomes `n`, `n+1`, `n+2`.

And your `table` has not enough spots to have an `n+2`. So you are trying to write to it and it just isn't there. So you get an error.

The easiest way to fix it might be to start with a larger list. But you should check your algorithm, too. You are calculating fibonacci values for two instances, even after you already know the value for `fib(n)`. That is not totally wrong, but certainly a waste. The algorithm should only calculate what you ask it to.